# Understanding the logic to extract frequency from a binary file to create huffman tree

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, binaryfiles, huffman-code

I have to claculate frequency from a binary files.

What i have in mind is i will do read the characters present in the file and then calculate frequency by the number of times that character repeats.
I do so using this code. And it works fine:

```
struct Node 
{
   unsigned char symbol;
   int appear;
   struct Node *link;
   struct Node * left,*right;
 };Node * head;
```

Somewhere in main i have like this to read the file:

```
   ch = fgetc(fp); 
   while (fread(&ch,sizeof(ch),1,fp))
    {
     symbol(ch);    
    }
    fclose(fp);
```

where add_symbol function is like this:

But i am not able to understand the logic of this code. Could any one please explain the questions i have asked in the code?

```
symbol(unsigned char sym) 
{
    Node*pt,*pt,*t;
    int is_there=0;
    pt = pt = head;
    while (pt != NULL) 
    { 
        if (pt -> symbol == sym) 
        {
            pt -> appear++;
            is_there = 1;
            break;
        }
        pt = pt;
        pt = pt -> link;
    }
    if (!is_there)
    {
        //  printf("\n is_there2 : %d\n",!is_there);
        printf("sym2 : %d\n", sym);
        t = (Node *) malloc(sizeof( Node));
        t -> symbol = sym;
        t -> appear = 1;
        t -> left = NULL;
        t -> right = NULL;
        t->link = NULL;
        if (head == NULL) 
        {
            head = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            pt->link = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

To find the same frequency we need to first store the all the data somewhere.

(1) Where it is done ?

(2) We need to compare the symbol if that appears again or not?

(3) Please explain bit more the code the logic is same in c and c++ as well. So any language , No problems.

In explain i have the doubt that:
suppose 1 2 1 3 3 1 2 are the symbols in binary file.
On first time execution of addsymbol we do addsymbol(1); , Now we store the "1" to know if any other "1" comes in future or not ? 
so we do pt->symbol if again equals to "1" then we increase frequency by one.
But on second execution of addsymbol we do addsymbol(2); which is not equal to "1" so again repeat.

On third time execution i got addsymbol(1); , this time i got "1" which equals to the "1" stored previously, so increases the frequency by "1".
What about the previous "2" ? Because we read the file only once by doing

```
while (fread(&ch,sizeof(ch),1,fp))
    {
     add_symbol(ch);    
    }
```

and if the "2" is already passed then we will not be able to count it. How this code persists this "2" and also finds it's frequency Please do not hesitate to ask me if you still don't undersand my question ?

Comment: Is this actually your code or did you just copy it from somewhere? Are you trying to understand how an implementation of a [huffman coding tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) works or just understand an actual implementation of it?

Comment: There are very few assignments and comparisons that are candidates for questions 1 and 2. It shouldn't be that hard to work it out. (BTW: You seem to imply that you wrote that code, yet you ask how it works?)

Comment: @StephenH I am trying to understand this code, It's not mine

Comment: @user252990, if you need to write a frequency calculator, how does copying someone else's code really help? You need to understand the principles of a huffman tree before you understand a programming implementation.

Comment: @StephenH I have edited the question please try to understand my question. It's not about the Huffman . It's about calculating the frequency (number of repetition of symbols). I have already created huffman tree using "Input.txt" file as sole argument containing alphabets like "aababccaddea" there i was first calculating the number of alphabets.suppose number = size then with that size i was calculating the frequency of each symbol by storing them and making comparisons with bad complexity.But this is the new way i am trying to understand.Could you please help me here on my question ? Thanks.

Comment: It's not necessary to store the frequencies of the data. It's simply enough to store the Huffman tree. Look at the zlib documents how a huffman tree can be perfectly recovered simply from the length of each symbol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code does not store all the data, it only stores the symbols and counts in a linked list.

The code reads one symbol at a time, calling add_symbol() for each. The `add_symbol` function starts by looking up the symbol in its linked list. If the symbol is there, the function will just increment its count; otherwise, it will add the symbol to the tail of the list, and with a count of 1.

**Edit:** By request, here's how it would look if it were more decomposed:

```
void Huffman::add_symbol(unsigned char sym)
{
    Node * foundNode = find_node_in_linked_list(sym);
    if(foundNode != NULL)
        foundNode->freq++;
    else
        add_freq1_node_at_end_of_list(sym);
}

Node* Huffman::find_node_in_linked_list(unsigned char sym)
{
    Node* pCur = Start;
    while(pCur != NULL)
    {
        if(pCur->symbol == ch)
            return pCur;
        pCur = pCur->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void Huffman::add_freq1_node_at_end_of_list(unsigned char sym)
{
    //Get tail of list
    Node* pTail = NULL;
    Node* pCur = Start;
    while(pCur != NULL)
    {
        pTail = pCur;
        pCur = pCur->next;
    }
    //Now, pTail is either the last element, or NULL if the list is empty.

    //Create the new object
    //(should use the new keyword instead, but since the deletion code was not posted...
    Node* pNew = static_cast< Node* >(malloc(sizeof *pNew)); 
    if(pNew == NULL)
        return;

    pNew->symbol = sym;
    pNew->freq = 1;
    pNew->left = NULL;
    pNew->right = NULL;
    pNew->next = NULL;
    pNew->is_processed = 0;

    //Add the new node at the tail
    if(pTail != NULL)
        pTail->next = pNew;
    else
        Start = pNew;
}
```

Note that it's less efficient than the big function because it goes through the list twice when the symbol is not found (once to try and find the symbol, once to find the tail).

In fact, there's no reason to specifically add at the tail rather than insert at the head.

---

Quite frankly a linked list is not the most time-efficient way of storing the counts for up to 256 symbols. Personnally I'd recommend using a lookup table instead (a dumb vector of 256 structures, or even a dedicated histogram object that would just be a vector of 256 integers).

Comment: Thanks for the help, Suppose 12133142342 symbols stored in a file. For the first time passes "1" addsymbol(1);and it is stored in ptr->symbol. for the next time addsymbol(2); but "2" is not equal to "1" so dont take it in account but next time addsymbol(1); , Now it found "1" so enhance the freq by one. (Question1:)But what about the previous "2" which we obtained on second execution of addasymbol(); which was not stored because it's frequency was not equal to "1"? (question:2) Do we need to check again for all "2" (and every symbol) all symbols to store it's freq

Comment: Your sentence *« but "2" is not equal to "1" so dont take it in account »* is completely false. The truth is *« but "2" is not equal to "1" so keep looping through the linked list until "2" is found; and if not found, add it with a frequency of 1. »*

Comment: Each call of `addsymbol` always executes as follows: 1, go through the linked list from the head (here, it's pointed by `start`) to find whether the symbol `sym` has existed in this list; 2, if yes, add the frequency (`pt -> freq++;`) and set `is_there` flag to return from this function; 3, if no, 'while' loop will make `ppt` point to the last node of this list and `is_there` will be `false`. Then a new node will be created by `malloc` and record the `sym`'s frequency with `1` (here, `temp -> freq = 1;`)

Comment: Medinoc (1)So what is the complexity of this procedure ?(2) I have edited my question to get answer exactly to the point. Thanks for trying helping me.

Comment: `O(N)` for each lookup, `N` being the number of different symbols. With `M` being the length of the file, we get `O(N*M)` for the entire histogram construction, while using a lookup table would make it `O(M)`

Comment: @Medinoc could you please write the same code in but simple programming code or algorithm for it ? It's really difficult to understand the logic.I am still not able to understand it.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**A few advices on your general design:**

Step #1: In order to count the symbols, you can use a simple histogram:

```
include <limits.h>
int histogram[1<<CHAR_BIT] = {0};
unsigned char ch;
while (fread(&ch,sizeof(ch),1,fp))
    histogram[ch]++;
```

Step #2: Now you need to use the histogram in order to build a Huffman tree:

- Create an array of `Node` pointers, one for each entry in `histogram` with a value greater than 0.
- Take this array and build a binary heap with the minimal value at the top.
- Run the following algorithm, until there is one element left in the heap:

  - Extract the first two `Node` elements from the heap.
  - Create a new `Node` whose children are these two `Node` elements.
  - Insert the new `Node` back into the heap.

Step #3: Now that you have a Huffman tree, please note the following:

- In order to encode the file, you need to use the leaves of the tree (given in the array of `Node` pointers created at the beginning of the previous step).
- In order to decode the file, you need to use the root of the tree (which is the last element left in the heap at the end of the previous step).

You can see a full example at:

http://planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=9737&lngWId=3.

Comment: Thanks for the help but i am obliged not to use any static declaration (No arrays) only pointers. I have already done what you said using array, This is my next step to understand properly the concepts of pointers.

Comment: This is not a bad answer, but it makes me sad that you're continuing the long tradition of promoting bit-by-bit decoding (I downloaded the code to see what it's doing). Bit-by-bit decoding should be nothing more than a first step in learning to understand the proper decoding algorithms.

Comment: No, all practical implementations use table-based decoding (and table-based encoding is trivial, of course).

Comment: But we're talking about Huffman encoding/decoding here, aren't we?

Comment: Yes of course, but instead of walking the tree, you just do a table lookup. The simplest version of that is to have one big table that's 2^max_symbol_length long, filled with entries that say what the first symbol is in the index and how many bits you have to shift out. Then you just index that thing with your buffer. There are some tricks to use less space.

Comment: Oh, OK, gotcha. It actually sounds pretty trivial to take this approach. I guess I didn't do so because my main focus was the Huffman algorithm... Thank you for the info :)

Comment: Yes, and encoding is even simpler, just collect all the patterns and their lengths in two arrays in one walk over the tree (if you're using canonical Huffman codes, which you should do, you only need the lengths and then generate the canonical patterns from them)

Comment: Oh wait, what about decoding an encoded file? How can I avoid "walking the bits" in that file (i.e., how do I know when to "grab" an encoded bit-sequence and find the corresponding decoded symbol)?

Comment: @barakmanos Could you please re-write the code of addsymbol() in my code in bit simple c/c++/or algorithm ?It's very complicated for me to understand it.Thanks for it

Comment: Ok this is getting a bit much for comments, I recommend reading [this](http://www.compressconsult.com/huffman/) and [this](http://www.arturocampos.com/ac_canonical_huffman.html) and [this](http://www.virtualdub.org/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=205) and if you need a pretty fast implementation, I've got one for you [here](http://www.omnimaga.org/index.php?topic=17401.0) (includes some stuff that is not Huffman codes, but you can separate that out)

Comment: Thanks @harold, I don't have any such needs at present, but I appreciate the enlightenment. Thanks again for the info :)

Comment: @harold Could you please re-write the code of addsymbol() in my code in bit simple c/c++/or algorithm ?It's very complicated for me to understand it.Thanks for it